# How do I make query return 0 when no records match in Access 2013?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a query in my Access 2013 database that counts the amount of records matching a certain criteria. However there are instances where no records will match and the query returns nothing. This is causing issues as I use this value in calculations. Please find the SQL code from my query below.

```
SELECT [Main Database].Renewal,
[Main Database].[2014/15 - Permission to Review],
Count(Main Database].[2014/15 - Permission to Review]) AS [CountOf2014/15 - Permission to Review]
FROM [Main Database]
GROUP BY [Main Database].Renewal, [Main Database].[2014/15 - Permission to Review]
HAVING ((([Main Database].Renewal) Like "**/05/****") AND (([Main Database].[2014/15 - Permission to Review])="Yes"));
```

I have tried using the Nz Function and IIF(IsNull([])), however neither of these seem to work.

Is there something I am doing wrong or alternative ways to achieve what I want?

Edit - New code with subquery

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS iniSumNov
FROM (
SELECT [Main Database].Renewal, [Main Database].[2014/15 - Initial Contact], 
Count([Main Database].[2014/15 - Initial Contact])
AS [CountOf2014/15 - Initial Contact]
FROM [Main Database]
GROUP BY [Main Database].Renewal, [Main Database].[2014/15 - Initial Contact]
HAVING ((([Main Database].Renewal) Like "**/11/****") AND (([Main Database].[2014/15 - Initial Contact])="Yes"))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNT(*) on a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NbRecords
FROM (
    SELECT ...whatever you need
     )
```

If the subquery is empty, the main query will return NbRecords = 0

Comment: I have tried using the suggestion above, however it comes up with an error message stating "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled".

Comment: At least you got a clear error message, telling you where to look at, now :-)

Comment: While using the above solution, it returns 0 where there are no records matching. However when there are multiple records with the same information it treats them as 1 and therefore the count is incorrect. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: That probably means the subquery returns a single row, or that you should add a primary key in the sub query to avoid Access doing an automatic "distinct" which seems to happen sometimes when you have duplicate rows. Eventually try adding a DISTINCTROW option to the subquery ?

Comment: I have tried adding DISTINCTROW and ALL to the subquery, but neither made a difference. I have added my new code, using the subquery, to the original question so you can see what I'm currently using.

Comment: if you run the subquery by itself how many rows does it give ? Is that correct ? If not you could have to remove the group by.

Comment: If I run the subquery by itself it returns 8 rows, however 3 of these rows have a value of 2 in the field I use to calculate. Therefore the count should return 11, however it only returns a count of 8. I'm guessing this is because it is counting the actual rows as opposed to the specific value in the field I want.

Comment: Do you use Count(*) or Count(field)? If you want RECORDS, you should use count(*).

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
 SELECT A.Renewal as Renewal ,
 A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review] as Permission_to_Review,
 IIF(isNull(Count(A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review])),0,Count(A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review])) AS count_Permission_to_Review 
 FROM [Main Database] A
 where (((A.Renewal) Like "**/05/****") AND ((A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review])="Yes")) 
 GROUP BY A.Renewal, A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review] 
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! I have trued the suggested code, however it is returning an error saying "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression. Any suggestions?

Comment: double space after `where`? another space after `IS NULL`? Might even be better to use `IsNull()` within an `IIf()`

Comment: removed spaces and used alias ..check it now

Comment: The query still returns nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post data of your table with table structure.

Comment: Try to run your query after removing where clause see if the records are filtering out .

Comment: I have remove the where clause and it returns results, however the filtering is a key part of the query.

Comment: Use this query select Renewal,Permission_to_Review,
iif( isNULL(countt),o,countt) 
from (
SELECT A.Renewal as Renewal ,
 A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review] as Permission_to_Review,
 Count(A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review]) as countt
 FROM [Main Database] A
 where (((A.Renewal) Like "**/05/****") AND ((A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review])="Yes")) 
 GROUP BY A.Renewal, A.[2014/15 - Permission to Review] )
;

Comment: I tried the above query and that didn't work either. I will put together the sample data and table structure for you.